# fetching not showing any result in email

Tags: php, email

I am a new with php.I make some forget password code this code is getting email from user.checking it in database if present in database then it sends password to the email.but here is a problem that i fetch a first_name from database to show in email header, but fetching script is not showing any result in email.
HERE IS MY CODE

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
function getRandomPassword($length=12, $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789"){
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
}


$town= $_POST['email'];
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $length = (int)$_POST['length'];

    if ($length < 6) $length = 6;

    $randomPassword = getRandomPassword($length); 

    $sender = '';
    $to = $town;
    $subject = 'Password Recovery';
    $from = 'johan.a.selin@gmail.com';
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Create email headers
    $headers .= 'From: '.$sender ."\r\n".
                'Reply-To: '.$user_email."\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    // Compose a simple HTML email message

    $message = '<html><body style=height:700px;>';
    $message = str_replace("{first_name}", $row['fname'], $message);
    $message .= '<img src="http://cashbackshopping.se/img/logoj.jpg" alt="cashbackshopping" height="50" width="150">';
    $message .= '<h1 style="color:white;width: 400px;height: 50px;text-align: center;margin-top: -3px;line-height: 2em;background: orange;">Hello!</h1>';
    $message .= '<p style="color:#1FA67A;font-size:18px;">Your requested a New Password </p>';
    $message .= '<p style="font-size:20px;color:red;">Your password is : <strong style="color:#38A1E3;    font-size: 30px;">' . $randomPassword . '</strong></p>';
    $message .= '<p style="font-size:20px;color:red;">Your First name is : <strong style="color:#38A1E3;    font-size: 30px;">' . $ename . '</strong></p>';
    $message .= $pass;
    $message .= '<br><button style="background: orange;    margin-left: 120px;    margin-top: 30px;
padding: 10px;"><a href="www.cashbackshopping.se/login.php" style="    background: orange;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 24px;color:#000;">Login here</a></button>';
    $message .= '<div style="width:400px;height:50px;background:#1fa67a;margin-top:30px;"><p style="text-align: center;line-height: 4em; color: white;">© 2014-2015 Cashbackshopping.se</p></div></body></html>';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

$str = $randomPassword;
$skspass= md5(sha1($str));
if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table 
             SET `password`='$skspass' 
             WHERE `email`='$town'";
    mysql_select_db('');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
          die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
}

//query
$query = mysql_query("select fname from cashbackengine_users WHERE email='$town'");

//write the results

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['name_first'];
    $ename = $row['name_first'];

    // close the loop
}

?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html). [Why are you limiting passwords?](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: Because this password will sended to email

Comment: Actually this 6 digit password is for temporarily login

Comment: can you please help me with this script

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: can you help me to print firstname in email

Comment: <?php
$message .= '<p style="font-size:20px;color:red;">Your First name is : <strong style="color:#38A1E3;    font-size: 30px;">' . $ename . '</strong></p>';

$query = mysql_query("select fname from cashbackengine_users WHERE email='$town'");

//write the results

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['name_first'];
    $ename = $row['name_first'];

// close the loop
}
?>

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new or updated information.

Comment: just help me to print the first name please.

Comment: `<?php $message .= '<p style="font-size:20px;color:red;">Your First name is : <strong style="color:#38A1E3; font-size: 30px;">' . $ename . '</strong></p>'; $query = mysql_query("select fname from cashbackengine_users WHERE email='$town'"); //write the results while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { echo $row['name_first']; $ename = $row['name_first']; // close the loop } ?>`

Comment: actually i am new with php and stackoverfrom

Comment: **if ( error_reporting(0) ) { "help_and_assistance = NO; }**

Comment: My script probmel is just it is not sending the first name in mail

Comment: the problem is here `$message = str_replace("{first_name}", $row['fname'], $message);` the ***chain*** link is broken. I should make this an answer. You should `str_replace()` first though.

Comment: `$message .= '<p style="font-size:20px;color:red;">Your First name is : <strong style="color:#38A1E3;    font-size: 30px;">' . $ename . '</strong></p>';` 
There it is not displaying $ename variable

Comment: Would you __PLEASE__ stop posting code in COMMENTS. It is totally unreadable. You can **edit your question** if you need to add or amend your question!